# Use custom domain with Office 365 family and migrate all email-accounts to outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, office-365, domain

I currently have my domain under management at some webspace-hoster for nameserver/webspace/emails. I want to move the webspace to GitHub-pages and move all the email imap-accounts completely to our Office 365 family account, where each one has its name@outlook.com address. I want to store/host/manage all the current emails in those outlook-accounts.

It seems I can only sync with existing email accounts or use a domain that is under GoDaddy-management. Is there any way to connect my domain with Office 365 family account?